# Spring Data Thymeleaf-cannot insert related record, foreign key null

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have 2 entities with one to many relationship. Related child entry fails to insert because foreign key is null. *Works in Tests though*.

Looked high and low, most were resolved because questioner didn't add child to parent, this is not my case. Any help appreciated!

**Error**

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("AIWA"."CAT_DT"."CAT_ID")

**Edit 1**: Adding detailed error log below.

> 2017-03-01 09:45:04 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:759 - Initiating
>   transaction commit 2017-03-01 09:45:04 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:512
>   - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@640a6fdf] 2017-03-01
>   09:45:04 DEBUG SQL:109 - 
>       insert 
>       into
>           CAT
>           (CATTYPE, ..., ID) 
>       values
>           (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 2017-03-01 09:45:04 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [NUMERIC] - [200] 2017-03-01
>   09:45:04 TRACE BasicBinder:69 - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] -
>   [null] 2017-03-01 09:45:04 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter
>   [3] as [VARCHAR] - [1] 2017-03-01 09:45:04 TRACE BasicBinder:69 -
>   binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [null] 2017-03-01 09:45:04 TRACE
>   BasicBinder:69 - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
>   2017-03-01 09:45:04 TRACE BasicBinder:69 - binding parameter [6] as
>   [VARCHAR] - [null] 2017-03-01 09:45:04 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding
>   parameter [7] as [NUMERIC] - [1] 2017-03-01 09:45:04 TRACE
>   BasicBinder:69 - binding parameter [8] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
>   2017-03-01 09:45:04 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [9] as
>   [NUMERIC] - [182] 2017-03-01 09:45:04 DEBUG SQL:109 - 
>       insert 
>       into
>           CAT_DT
>           (CAT_ID, DESCR, LANGUAGE, NAME, SORTNAME, ID) 
>       values
>           (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 2017-03-01 09:45:04 TRACE BasicBinder:69 - binding parameter [1] as [NUMERIC] - [null] 2017-03-01 09:45:04 TRACE
>   BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [a] 2017-03-01
>   09:45:04 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [3] as [NUMERIC] -
>   [1] 2017-03-01 09:45:04 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [4]
>   as [VARCHAR] - [a] 2017-03-01 09:45:04 TRACE BasicBinder:69 - binding
>   parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [null] 2017-03-01 09:45:04 TRACE
>   BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [6] as [NUMERIC] - [264] 2017-03-01
>   09:45:04 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:144 - SQL Error: 1400, SQLState:
>   23000 2017-03-01 09:45:04 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - ORA-01400:
>   cannot insert NULL into ("CAT_DT"."CAT_ID")
>
> 2017-03-01 09:45:04 INFO  AbstractBatchImpl:208 - HHH000010: On
>   release of batch it still contained JDBC statements 2017-03-01
>   09:45:04 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:898 - Initiating transaction
>   rollback after commit exception

**Entities**

```
public class Cat{
    private List<CatDt> catDts = new ArrayList<CatDt>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "cat", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<CatDt> getCatDts() {
        if(this.catDts==null){
            this.catDts = new ArrayList<CatDt>();
        }
        return this.catDts;
    }

    public void setCatDts(List<CatDt> catDts) {
        this.catDts = catDts;
    }
}

public class CatDt{
    private Cat cat;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAT_ID", nullable = false)
    public Cat getCat() {
        return this.cat;
    }

    public void setCat(Cat cat) {
        this.cat = cat;
    }
}
```

**Thymeleaf form**

```
<ul th:each="item, stat: *{catDts}">
    <li>
        <span th:text="#{front.cat.CatDt.no.label}">No</span>
        <label th:text="${stat.count}">1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span th:text="#{front.cat.CatDt.name.label}">Name</span>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{catDts[__${stat.index}__].name}" th:id="${'name-'+stat.index}">
    </li>
    <li>
        <span th:text="#{front.cat.CatDt.descr.label}">Description</span>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{catDts[__${stat.index}__].descr}" th:id="${'descr-'+stat.index}">
    </li>
    <li>
        <span th:text="#{front.cat.CatDt.lang.label}">Language</span>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{catDts[__${stat.index}__].language}" th:id="${'language-'+stat.index}">
    </li>       
</ul>
```

**Resulting HTML form**

```
<form action="/aiwaweb/cat/create" method="post">
    <!-- Main info -->
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>Code</span>
            <input id="code" name="code" value="" type="text">          
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Type</span>
            <select id="catType" name="catType">
                <option...>...</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Status</span>
            <select id="status" name="status">
                <option value="0">INACTIVE</option>
                <option value="1">ACTIVE</option>
            </select>
        </li>           
    </ul>

    <!-- Details -->    
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>No.</span>
            <label>1</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Name</span>
            <input id="name-0" name="catDts[0].name" value="" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Description</span>
            <input id="descr-0" name="catDts[0].descr" value="" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Language</span>
            <input id="language-0" name="catDts[0].language" value="" type="text">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**Edit 2** Updated controller create() to add Cat to CatDt as well (earlier it was just adding catDt to Cat); hoped this 2 way relationship linking would solve but didn't.

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping({"/create"})
public String create(ModelMap model){
    Cat cat = new Cat();
    List<CatDt> catDts = new ArrayList<CatDt>();
    CatDt catDt = new CatDt();
    catDt.setCat(cat); //this is the extra line added
    catDts.add(catDt);
    cat.setCatDts(catDts);
    model.addAttribute("cat", cat);
    return "cat/create";
}

@PostMapping(value="/create", params={"save"})
public String save(final Cat cat
        , final BindingResult bindingResult, final ModelMap model){
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return "cat/create";
    }
    Cat updatedCat = catService.save(cat);
    model.clear();
    return "redirect:/cat/create";
}
```

**What I did so far**

1. When I debug on my controller save(), the Cat has children CatDt in a List, but the cat property of CatDt is null; but come to think of it, maybe it should be null as Cat is not saved yet, so no Id yet.

**Unit Test**

```
@Test
public void testCatSave(){
    Cat cat = new Cat();
    cat.setCode("11111");
    ...     
    //add cat details
    List<CatDt> catDts = new ArrayList<CatDt>();        
    CatDt catDt = new CatDt();
    catDt.setCat(cat);
    catDt.setName("Test");
    ...
    catDts.add(catDt);
    cat.setCatDts(catDts);          
    Cat catUpdated = catService.save(cat);
}
```

**Persistence Config**

```
public class PersistenceConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
    {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("ae.tbits.atn.aiwacore.common.model");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf)
    {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator(){
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.type"));
        return properties;        
    }     
}
```

Following this to a T, but not saving child records http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#the-controller

Comment: Added Edit 1 showing a bit more of the log. Can see the 2 sets of insert statements for parent & child. Somehow _child not getting newly inserted parent id_ . Do I need to do anything manually such as _commit_ or _flush_ ? If yes where because I tried and my mvc code threw error ( _no transaction in progress_ ). My service simply calls repo's Cat.save(); Tests run fine. Or some changes in Entity or config required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so finally I was able to resolve. Turns out somehow the children catDts were not being added to the cat object.

In controller save() I reassigned manually and it saved.

```
public String save(final Cat cat
        , final BindingResult bindingResult, final ModelMap model){
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        logger.info("Binding result error in create(save)");
        return "cat/create";
    }
    //manually reassign - start
    List<CatDt> catDts = cat.getCatDts();
    for (CatDt catDt : catDts) {
        catDt.setCat(cat);
    }
    cat.setCatDts(catDts);
    //manually reassign - end

    Cat updatedCat = catService.save(cat); //saveAndFlush
    model.clear();
    return "redirect:/cat/create";

}
```

Although this worked, I think somehow my thymeleaf form wasn't set up properly hence it wasn't linking, so anyone is welcome to throw in an explanation.

Thanks.